# How do I bind a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have a `ComboBox` and need to bind it to a `DataGrid`. How can I do that?

Comment: Repeating the title in the body of the question helps no one.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<tk:DataGrid x:Name="dgProducts" DataContext="GoodsCollection" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
         <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
               <tk:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Good Name" 
                    x:Name="dgCbProduct" 
                            TextBinding="{Binding Path=GoodID, Converter={StaticResource GoodIDToGoodNameConverter}}"
                            SelectedValuePath="GoodName" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="GoodName">
                            </tk:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
          </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I'd bind the object collection to ItemsSource instead of DataContext, personally.